# Can I tell git how to merge conflicts in a line without intervention?

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

In our Rails application, as is pretty standard, we have a `schema.rb` file which starts like this:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_03_12_084500) do
```

The `version` constant is the timestamp of when the file was generated.

Our procedure for running migrations in production means that it's fairly common for a migration written on Monday to be merged on Thursday and one written on Tuesday to be merged on Friday - but Thursday's merge will cause a Tuesday's migration to have conflict in git, so its branch has to be rebased and the pull request re-approved before Friday's merge can happen.  It's also fairly common for Monday's migration to be merged on Friday and Tuesday's on Thursday.

It's annoying, and it's a drain on a limited resource, and the rules around merging are always the same: the later change to that line always wins.  So it needs to be automated.

What I'd really like is to be able to write something like

```rb
# git auto merge: pick-last-by-date
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_03_12_084500) do
# git auto merge end
```

and then git would know that if there are two changes involving only that line then it should
pick the latest version and proceed without conflict.

Our merges happen on GitHub, and any new pushes to the branch from us dismiss the pull request's approval (and that's a good feature which we want to keep) so a local plugin wouldn't help here. If the remote instance of git thinks there's a conflict, then our workflow is blocked.

Does vanilla git - or I suppose GitHub's version of git, if that's different - have a feature that would let us define automatic merge conflict resolution for that one line?

Comment: In *local* Git, you can write a *merge driver* that handles this sort of thing (though that's not an easy task). On GitHub, you can't define merge drivers like this though.

Comment: @torek good to know - thanks.